# Add values to RestKit mapping result dictionary after mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I use RestKit 0.20 to call into an endpoint. This endpoint requires a parameter that holds a signature, as a type of validation. This signature depends on the request parameters: if for instance we want to send `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}`, the signature is calculated as `hash("somesecretfoo1bar2")`, which then should be added to the payload such that it in the end is like `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2, "sig": "oursignature"}`.

I am not sure what the best way is to achieve this with RestKit. I can hook it into every separate request description, but as it is the same process for each request, I would like to hook it into the request operation, after the mapping is done.

How can I do this?

I looked into overloading `RKObjectRequestOperation`, but couldn't see exactly where to put this, and whether I could then still use `RKObjectManager`'s `appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject`.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at modifying your data model classes, perhaps with a common superclass, so that you have an `- (NSString *)sig` method that you can use in your mappings. This method can gather all of the keys and values that will be sent (perhaps using `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`).

This should be easier, and more maintainable, that trying to modify the RestKit classes.

An alternative, and rather than trying to subclass `RKObjectRequestOperation`, would be to subclass `RKNSJSONSerialization` and set the subclass as the serialiser to use on the object manager (`[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:forMIMEType:]`).

Then, you can implement `dataFromObject:error:` to mutate the `object` passed, process the contents and add the new key/value pair and then call `super`.

Comment: That would be much better yeah. Unfortunately, the classes don't know what keys they will be mapped to at all times, and not all keys are used all the time, so I don't think I can do this.